# How to remove '$' from EditText, modify the float, and put a $ back

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to get the float value from a EditText, add some number to it, then change whatever number was there before. I have had no problem with that - the code below works. What I want to do is make it so that a '$' is always displayed infront of the float. I don't have much problem putting the $ there, as I just make the setText to setText("$"+iprice3). The problem comes about when I take in the value from EditText and there is a '$' present - it makes the app crash. I am having trouble figuring out how to go to string, get rid of it, then go back to float. Any ideas?

```
if(checkbox3.isChecked())
{
    EditText price3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.payment3);
    float floatprice3 = Float.valueOf(price3.getText().toString());
    float newprice3 = everyOnePaying + floatprice3;
    String iprice3 = Float.toString(newprice3);
    price3.setText(iprice3);
    checkbox3.setChecked(false);
}
```

On a side note - I was wondering if anyone knew how I could format the float so that it displays only 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do as

```
String fltprice = price3.getText().toString().replace("$","");

float floatprice3 = Float.valueOf(fltprice);
float newprice3 = everyOnePaying + floatprice3;
//String iprice3 = Float.toString(newprice3);
//price3.setText("$" + iprice3);
```

if you wish to just display then you can display as

```
price3.setText("$" + String.format(%.2f,newprice3));
```

Comment: Everything works but your formatting - it crashes and says "%f can't format java.lang.String Arguments"

Comment: check edit. actually my mistake. you need to pass the float directly.

Comment: Wow. Unbelievable. I have tried so many things and this is the only one that has worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
float floatprice3 = Float.valueOf(price3.getText().toString().substring(1));
```

And use DecimalFormat to place a restriction on 2 decimal places

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(364565.14));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = editText1.getText().toString();
str1 = str1.replace("$","");

String str2 = editText2.getText().toString();
str2 = str2.replace("$","");

Float f1 = Float.parseFloat (str1);
Float f2 = Float.parseFloat (str2);

Float sum = f1 + f2;


 String result = String.format("$%.2f", sum);
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I integrate the 'str' into my current code? I need to make it a float so that I can add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do step by step like this

```
String fromEditText = price3.getText().toString();// receiving string from edittext
String youWant=fromEditText.subString(1);    //removing firstcharacter
float yourfloatValue=Float.valueOf(youWant); // converting into float
```

now use this float value

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(your view id);
String s = et.getText().toString().replace("$", "");
Float f = Float.valueOf(s);
```

This should remove $ from the editText filed.

On your side note you can do this to format your float to limit to 2 digit of decimal:

```
f = 22.3986;
f = Math.round(f*100)/100.0;
```

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track just append the dollar sign and format it

**sample:**

```
String.format("$%.2f", Float.valueOf(price3.getText()));; //set the float with dollar sign 2 decimal places
```

Now to get the text and parse it to float you need to replace the dollar sign and parse it.

```
float value = Float.valueOf(price3.getText().replace("$", "")); //replace the float's dollaar sign and transform it to float
```